# sap.m.SearchField not showing suggestion items

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to make a searchable field for an order creation screen. I decided to use `sap.m.SearchField`. To search, I bound it to an oData source.

Here's a [JSbin](https://jsbin.com/menoxi/edit?html,output). If you comment out the `//debugger` statement you can see with `oEvent.getSource().getAggregation('suggestionItems')` that some stuff seems set.

```
    <SearchField
        type="Text"
        enableSuggestions="true"
        suggest="onMaterialSuggest"
        suggestionItems="{path: 'part>/Parts'}">
        <suggestionItems>
            <SuggestionItem text="{part>PartDesc}" description="{data>PartID}" key="{part>PartID}"/>
        </suggestionItems>
    </SearchField>
```

`onMaterialSuggest` has code that looks like:

```
var value = oEvent.getSource().getValue().toUpperCase();
var filters = [];
filters.push(new Filter({
    filters: [
        new Filter("PartID", Operator.Contains, value.toUpperCase()),
        new Filter("PartDesc", Operator.Contains, value.toUpperCase())
    ],
    and: false
}));

oEvent.getSource().getBinding('suggestionItems').filter(filters);
```

The searching and filtering works, I can see the calls in the console
[image]

The items are bound, I can do a `getAggregation('suggestionItems')` and I can see that it's full of things. 
[image]

Problem is that the suggestions do not actually show. I feel I'm missing something silly. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Certainly looks well formed. Would it be possible to recreate a snippet on e.g. jsbin to have a further look into this?

Comment: Could you suggest a public oData service? Then I can give it a shot

Comment: Sample OData Service: http://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/

Comment: I'm only wasting time getting a jsbin to work: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 501` pff.

Comment: Cors is always a tough cookie. If you like, you can use cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com as a proxy in your jsbin, e.g.: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/. Have a look at https://jsbin.com/sunanigama to see how that works from a UI5 jsbin.

Comment: Added a JSbin, see question.

Comment: Had a look already, but found everything just looks right. Will have another fresh look tomorrow morning.

Comment: It does appear that you're missing the .suggest() call in the bottom of the onSuggest method. But even after adding that, I didn't get it to work. Only after I changed the ODataModel to a JSON model, things started moving. If you like, you can have a look at a revised jsbin on https://jsbin.com/pogolap/4/edit?html,output, in which the JSON Model has been added. To use the ODataModel instead, just remove the the line that says "odata" (and the preceding comma). You'll see that it stops working then. My suggestion would be to file an issue for this on https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues

Comment: @jpenninkhof thanks. I can't use json because the search is huge. I have already logged an issue (number 1027 from memory) with the openui5 people but no response so far.

Comment: @jorg I already guessed that that would be the reason that you're using OData. That doesn't disqualify the JSONModel though. It just involves a bit more manual work. Just make sure that on every onSuggest, you don't fill the JSONModel with too much data, and make sure the initial content of the JSONModel is limited to e.g. the first 100 entries. When you submit an issue to the OpenUI5 team, make sure you refer to the jsbin in the issue as well. UI5 developers also love that stuff. If your company has enterprise support (i.e. SAPUI5), you may also want to log a ticket with active global support